# How to determine present operating system (including specific distribution in the case of Linux) in a Vala program?

Tags: operating-system, vala

I am interested in writing a Vala program that will determine the present operating system and act accordingly (exactly how it will act I have not decided yet, but is not relevant to this question). So what I would like to know is how I might determine the present operating system (including the specific distribution in the case of Linux) in a Vala program at runtime.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634474/is-os-detection-possible-with-glib

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678842/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-which-linux-distribution-is-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are writing system level code (like package manager or OS configuration code), **you shouldn't**. A much better alternative is to use a library that already abstracts the distribution specifics for you.

If you absolutely have to there are two main ways to do it:

1. At build time

   Here your build system should be responsible to detect the OS / distribution and either pass a define to the compiler (like `-DDISTRO_UBUNTU`) or write a `config.vala` file (possibly from a template `config.vala.in` with replacements, e.g. autotools has the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` facility to do this).
2. At runtime

   Here your tool does the detection itself when it's running.

Which fits your application better is a design choice.

As to how to do it there are several things you can check:

- `uname -a` (or other parameters, see man uname) will give you the kernel that is currently running.
- `lsb_release -a` (not available on every distro, sometimes an optional package which you might have a package dependency to) will give you information on what distro and what distro version you are running on.
- On Debian/Ubuntu derivates there is a file called `/etc/debian_version` which gives an indication of what release is currently installed. That information is not totally accurate though.
- Some people are trying to read `/etc/issue`, but that is dangerous, since that file could be modified by the admin / the user.
- You could ask the user which OS she is running.

There are also some os info libraries that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) syscall (how to do that in Vala is left as an exercise to the user), or read `/proc/version` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), or read `/etc/issues` or follow [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) conventions (e.g.`popen` the output of `lsb_release -a`).

But as Jens Mühlenhoff [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41313893/841108), **you should not do that**, and avoid writing code depending on some particular distribution.

And some users might want to fake or hide that information (think of someone having some "[Linux From Scratch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_From_Scratch)" system).